# In Java, why isn't nextInt() retrieving every number from this text file?

Tags: java, matrix, int, java.util.scanner

```
  public GameofLife(int gen)
  {
   generations = gen; 
   life = new boolean[20][20];
   try {
      Scanner pablo = new Scanner(new File("life100.txt"));
      pablo.nextInt(); //eliminate 100 (number of files in the list)
      while (pablo.hasNextInt())
          {
            life[pablo.nextInt()][pablo.nextInt()] = true;
          }
        } catch(Exception e){}
     out.print(Arrays.deepToString(life));
    }
```

I'm trying to read in 100 pairs int coordinates for an array from a text file, but for some reason this setup doesn't get every number; after it reads in row 3 it stops.
The text file is in the setup

```
100
1    3
1    7
1    8
1   11
1   12
1   17
2    1
2    5
2    8
3    7
3   13
3   16
3   20
4    1
4    5
4   15
4   17
```

and goes all the way up to 19 18. Yet when I print it, with the     `out.print(Arrays.deepToString(life));`, every position after row three is false, whereas I'm setting this up so that every pair of coordinates on the text file starts as true in the matrix.

Is this a problem with my `nextInt()` scanner function? Or something else? And what is the best way to fix it? 
Please I need help. Any advice, comments, or ideas are welcome. Thank you

Comment: `The text file is in the setup 100` Can you elaborate on what you mean by this? Also, `pablo.nextInt(); //eliminate 100 (number of files in the list)`. How does your comment and the code next to it make sense?

Comment: Code looks alright. Probably some junk character in file? The biggest mistake I see you have done is to catch `Exception` and do nothing. Print stacktrace to get better idea.

Comment: Empty catch blocks are **evil**. Never write them, never even think about writing them. They silently swallow errors and you end up asking questions here without giving us enough information to answer them.

Comment: In response to Chetan Kinger, I had been taught that in most text files the first number usually tells you how many integers are in the rest of the file. So the 100, indicates that there are 100 integers after it. And to Aniket and Boris, I initially didn't have the catch exception but it was throwing an error so a peer advised me to use it and it got rid of the compile error. Can you elaborate on stacktrace? I've never used it before.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Unfamiliar with notifying using at... ^ comment above is intended for you

Comment: Also, use a `try-with-resources` block to close your `Scanner`. Not closing external resources after use is a very good way to create a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the actual file content it looks like you're exceeding the bounds of your array when it reads in `3   20`  There is no `[3][20]` allocated in `life`, it would only go out to `[3][19]`.

This is being obscured by your try/catch block which catches and drops the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  As the comments suggest, printing a stack trace is a better default catch behavior than doing nothing, which would quickly reveal this error.

Try putting `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch block to see what I'm talking about.

Since Java arrays are indexed starting from 0, if your file contains row+column positions going from 1 to 20, you need to subtract 1 from the value in the file before adding it to the array, e.g.

`life[pablo.nextInt() - 1][pablo.nextInt() - 1] = true;`

Comment: That sounds very promising, but when I eliminate the try/catch block I get this error which stops it from compiling.    `1 error found:
File: /Users/samamore/Desktop/Comp Sci/Weekly Projects Q3/GameofLife.java  [line: 29]
Error: /Users/samamore/Desktop/Comp Sci/Weekly Projects Q3/GameofLife.java:29: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown `

Comment: Which line is line 29?

Comment: Line 29 is : `Scanner pablo = new Scanner(new File("life100.txt"));`

Comment: @namore No one asked you to remove the `try-catch`. All you had to do was add the `e.printStackTrace()` call between the opening and closing curly braces of the catch block.

Comment: Yes, any file IO operation can throw an exception and needs to be either caught and handled (i.e. by printing stack trace and exiting) or passing the buck to the calling function using `throws`, just like that error says.

Comment: @FoolishSeth Ahhhh... Ok now it works, but like Seth said, I have the index out of bounds error, which I will adjust with the -1. Thank you guys